# Active record writing a variable into mysql with ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I want to perform the multiple tests within one URL, over may different URL's.

I have code that works and writes to my mysql database but it only writes exactly what I put into the double quotes. If I wanted to define `"x"` or `"mywebsite"` as a variable and then have active record write the current value of the variable into the database how could I do this?

My code is currently:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
for x in a.each do
    if browser.text.include?(x.chomp)
        class Rubyist < ActiveRecord::Base
        Rubyist.create(:name => "x", :city => "mywebsite")
    end
end
```

Where "a" is an array of variables. And "mywebsite" is changed at the start of each test. the tests runs through and repeats for each value of x in the array.

If I put:

```
        Rubyist.create(:name => x, :city => mywebsite)
```

Then I get   an error along the lines of:

```
some/long.path/to/active_record/base.rb:1014:in 'method_missing': undefined local variable or method 'x' for Rubyist(id: integer, name: string, city: text):Class (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think `for x in a.each do` is redundant, but it does seem to work...

Let me try answering your question again. The problem seems to be that you don't close the definition of your class.

This means the following is inside the class definition, where `x` is not defined:

```
Rubyist.create(:name => x, :city => mywebsite)
```

To fix this you have to close the class definition, before calling `Rubyist.create`:

```
if browser.text.include?(x.chomp)
  class Rubyist < ActiveRecord::Base; end
  Rubyist.create(:name => x, :city => mywebsite)
end
```

Comment: this code does work. It is not related the the problem i am having.

Comment: @Benjamin, you're right that code does work. I updated my answer with another (possible) solution to your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't run at all if I put this extra "; end" in.

Comment: Thanks, this works now, I just had to play around with the positioning of some "end"s. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Characters enclosed in single or double quotes are a string.  Since your variable is named `x`, just call it that instead of wrapping it in quotes.

```
Rubyist.create(:name => x, :city => mywebsite)
```

Comment: When I do this i get an error that reads something like "path/to/active_record/base.rb:1014:in 'method_missing'" and then a list of missing bits then it crashes.

Comment: @Benjamin: sounds like you haven't defined `x` or `mywebsite`.  Update your question with the code that defines those.

Comment: x is defined from an external word pad file. and is just a single word. mywebsite is a full URL. I am using Watir, and the code visits the websites, so I can see that they are defined outside this bit of the code for the active record.

Comment: @Benjamin: `x` is a local variable.  you need to define it where your test runs.